# Signalr setting request identity in HubPipelineModule

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to add existing oauth authentication to the new signalr hub implementation. I created a custome authentication module which inherits from **HubPipelineModule** and registered it at the startup.

I was able to use existing authentication logic to setup thread's currentPrincipal and it works with standard asp.net webapi request, however it doesn't work for signalr request. I am trying to override the "OnBeforeAuthorizeConnect" method and set the request's (IRequest) user  identity to the ClaimsIdentity i have create and authenticated.

however, the request's user identity is readyonly, my question is what is the proper way to set the request user's identity in signalr request.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at this link. It has a SignalR authentication feature built into it.

https://github.com/louislewis2/AngularJSAuthentication

you could look at the Attribute that decorates the hub class and then navigate to the implementation
of the attribute.

Regards

Louis